# Reading file of unspaced integers – hasNextInt() never returns true

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, filereader, java-io

I'm trying to read a list of unspaced integers from a file and I can't figure out why I never get past the conditional in my while loop.

This is the entire "nums.txt" file:

```
12121212121212121212121212121212
00001212121212121212121212121212
33331212121212121212121212121212
```

And the little script looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("nums.txt"))));
      while(reader.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println(reader.nextInt());
      }
     reader.close()
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When run, this outputs nothing, and terminates.

Comment: How can you tell when one number ends and the next number begins? Are they all only single digit numbers? If that is the case use a read character method and convert the character to an int.

Comment: That's what I had settled on, but it seemed so obtuse I was wondering if there was a better way...which I guess is a more specific question than what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional solution to this issue, by reading chars and returning the values as they are in the file:

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("nums.txt")));
    while(reader.read()%48 != -1){
      System.out.println(reader.read()%48);
    }
```

Because the file could contain newlines and other characters, one would need to do additional parsing to accept only the desired numbers as they are returned.

Or using Scanner:

```
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("nums.txt"));
    while(reader.hasNextLine())
    for (String token : reader.nextLine().split("(?!^)"))
        System.out.println(token);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to its JavaDoc `Scanner.hasNextInt()`:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method.

`12121212121212121212121212121212` is the next token, and it can't be interpreted as an int, because the maximum int is 2147483647.

Therefore `hasNextInt()` returns `false`, and your loop ends.

A `Scanner` by its nature works on tokens split by a delimiter (by default, space). If you want to consume one char at a time use `Reader.read()` or even `InputStream.read()`.

Comment: Great answer, however substituting hasNextByte() and nextByte() for hasNextInt() and nextInt(), doesn't change the functionality – the program still outputs nothing and terminates.

Comment: Apologies -- I made the same mistake you did of not reading the docs. `nextByte()` parses number strings in exactly the same way as `nextInteger()`. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. Be sure to do something with each int that gets generated or you'll loose it.

```
BufferedReaderreader = new new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("nums.txt")));

while ((currentChar = br.read()) != null) {
    // discard white space
    if (!java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(currentChar))
            int x = Integer.parseInt(currentChar)
            // do something with the int
}
```